# Linux, how to add "missing" i2c interface?

Tags: linux, embedded, device-tree

I'm working on an embedded project utilizing a Digi ConnectCore 6UL SBC Pro, and I know that `dmesg` should show me the three I2C interfaces after boot up like:

```
i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered
i2c i2c-0: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
i2c i2c-1: IMX I2C adapter registered
i2c i2c-1: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
i2c i2c-2: IMX I2C adapter registered
i2c i2c-2: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
```

I spun up my own image which boots fine and all but instead of three, it only gets two interfaces:

```
i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered
i2c i2c-0: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
i2c i2c-1: IMX I2C adapter registered
i2c i2c-1: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
```

Where is the third interface, I'm wondering?
Also, `i2cdetect` gives the following results:
Original image:

```
# i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c             21a4000.i2c                             I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c             21a8000.i2c                             I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c             21a0000.i2c                             I2C adapter
```

vs new image:

```
# i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c             21a4000.i2c                             I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c             21a0000.i2c                             I2C adapter
```

it looks like, the kernel cannot see the I2C interface at address 21a8000. How can I modify my build so that it sees the third I2C device, also? I've been looking into the device tree file but am not exactly sure where to look, modify and fix this.

Any hints, pointers & suggestions are welcome!

**/usr/local/dey-2.2~/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/i2c/i2c-imx.txt:**

```
* Freescale Inter IC (I2C) and High Speed Inter IC (HS-I2C) for i.MX

Required properties:
- compatible :
  - "fsl,imx1-i2c" for I2C compatible with the one integrated on i.MX1 SoC
  - "fsl,imx21-i2c" for I2C compatible with the one integrated on i.MX21 SoC
  - "fsl,vf610-i2c" for I2C compatible with the one integrated on Vybrid vf610 SoC
- reg : Should contain I2C/HS-I2C registers location and length
- interrupts : Should contain I2C/HS-I2C interrupt
- clocks : Should contain the I2C/HS-I2C clock specifier

Optional properties:
- clock-frequency : Constains desired I2C/HS-I2C bus clock frequency in Hz.
  The absence of the property indicates the default frequency 100 kHz.
- dmas: A list of two dma specifiers, one for each entry in dma-names.
- dma-names: should contain "tx" and "rx".
- scl-gpios: specify the gpio related to SCL pin
- sda-gpios: specify the gpio related to SDA pin
- pinctrl: add extra pinctrl to configure i2c pins to gpio function for i2c
  bus recovery, call it "gpio" state

Examples:

i2c@83fc4000 { /* I2C2 on i.MX51 */
        compatible = "fsl,imx51-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
        reg = <0x83fc4000 0x4000>;
        interrupts = <63>;
};

i2c@70038000 { /* HS-I2C on i.MX51 */
        compatible = "fsl,imx51-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
        reg = <0x70038000 0x4000>;
        interrupts = <64>;
        clock-frequency = <400000>;
};

i2c0: i2c@40066000 { /* i2c0 on vf610 */
        compatible = "fsl,vf610-i2c";
        reg = <0x40066000 0x1000>;
        interrupts =<0 71 0x04>;
        dmas = <&edma0 0 50>,
                <&edma0 0 51>;
        dma-names = "rx","tx";
        pinctrl-names = "default", "gpio";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&pinctrl_i2c1_gpio>;
        scl-gpios = <&gpio5 26 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        sda-gpios = <&gpio5 27 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
};
```

Hi, I apologize for the long absence and would like to continue on this ticket from here. As @dirkt suggested in his/her comment, I searched for dts and dtsi files in my kernel sources but found way too many files:

```
$ locate .dts | grep /arch/arm | grep /boot/dts | grep /usr/local/dey-2.2 | wc -l
1541
```

and adding `| grep -i i2c` in place of the `| wc -l` above did not give me any results. So how do I go about adding the `I2C` devices to my device tree at the correct location, I'm wondering?

I can find the below related `*.dts` files:

```
$ find . -name "*imx6ul*.dts"
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-tx6ul-0011.dts
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-tx6ul-0010.dts
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-tx6ul-mainboard.dts
```

and after grepping for `i2c`, it looks like none of these files align with the i2c output that I see above...:

```
$ find . -name "*imx6ul*.dts" | xargs grep -i i2c
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:&i2c1 {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:      pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:&i2c2 {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:      pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:&i2c3 {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:      pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c3>;
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:      pinctrl_i2c1: i2c1grp {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:                      MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO02__I2C1_SCL          0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:                      MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO03__I2C1_SDA          0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:      pinctrl_i2c2: i2c2grp {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:                      MX6UL_PAD_UART5_TX_DATA__I2C2_SCL       0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:                      MX6UL_PAD_UART5_RX_DATA__I2C2_SDA       0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:      pinctrl_i2c3: i2c3grp {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:                      MX6UL_PAD_UART1_TX_DATA__I2C3_SCL       0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-pico-hobbit.dts:                      MX6UL_PAD_UART1_RX_DATA__I2C3_SDA       0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:&i2c2 {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:        pinctrl_i2c1: i2c1grp {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:                        MX6UL_PAD_UART4_TX_DATA__I2C1_SCL 0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:                        MX6UL_PAD_UART4_RX_DATA__I2C1_SDA 0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:        pinctrl_i2c2: i2c2grp {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:                        MX6UL_PAD_UART5_TX_DATA__I2C2_SCL 0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-14x14-evk.dts:                        MX6UL_PAD_UART5_RX_DATA__I2C2_SDA 0x4001b8b0
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-tx6ul-mainboard.dts:&i2c_gpio {
./tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-tx6ul-mainboard.dts:&i2c2 {
```

I found:
i2c1: i2c@021a0000 {
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;
compatible = "fsl,imx6ul-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
reg = <0x021a0000 0x4000>;
interrupts = <GIC_SPI 36 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
clocks = <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_I2C1>;
status = "disabled";
};

```
                    i2c2: i2c@021a4000 {
                            #address-cells = <1>;
                            #size-cells = <0>;
                            compatible = "fsl,imx6ul-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
                            reg = <0x021a4000 0x4000>;
                            interrupts = <GIC_SPI 37 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                            clocks = <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_I2C2>;
                            status = "disabled";
                    };

                    i2c3: i2c@021a8000 {
                            #address-cells = <1>;
                            #size-cells = <0>;
                            compatible = "fsl,imx6ul-i2c", "fsl,imx21-i2c";
                            reg = <0x021a8000 0x4000>;
                            interrupts = <GIC_SPI 38 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                            clocks = <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_I2C3>;
                            status = "disabled";
                    };
```

in
`cortexa7hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/4.8-r0/linux-4.8/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul.dtsi` which presumably is the device tree file i'm dealing with. What's noteworthy is, that the status for all i2c interfaces is set to `"disabled"`

Comment: Have you found the part in the device tree file where the working I2C adapters are specified?

Comment: @dirkt there's something in a file called `i2c-imx.txt` but I'm not sure if that is the right place to be honest...

Comment: I mean, it's really difficult for us to judge if we cannot see those files ...

Comment: @dirkt I've pasted the file above

Comment: That's the documentation from the kernel source (which explains how to fill out the actual device tree file). The device files themselves should have endings `.dts` or `.dtsi` (for includes), and you need to start with the main file for your architecture, where ever this is located in your custom kernel (under `arch/arm/boot/dts`, if they follow the convention).

Comment: @dirkt There are many `.dts` iles under `$ ls -l  ccimx6ulstarter-dey-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-fw-utils/v2016.03+gitAUTOINC+df61a74e68-r0/git/arch/arm/dts/` but none that refers to `*i2c*`

Comment: Hi @dirkt I added more info to the bottom of my post above, would you be able to provide further guidance? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are booting from an SD card, you should be able to find a `*.dtb` file on there. This compiled device tree file tells the kernel which hardware is available. You can replace it with a custom one compiled from a `*.dts` file.

In the upstream Linux source code I see [imx6ul-ccimx6ulsbcpro.dts](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul-ccimx6ulsbcpro.dts) which should be the one for your board. However, it seems to only enable `i2c1`. In the included [imx6ul.dtsi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ul.dtsi) we see that there are in fact four I2C interfaces.

At least if you are using an upstream Linux kernel, you should be able to enable the third I2C interface by adding following to `mx6ul-ccimx6ulsbcpro.dts`:

```
&i2c3 {
    status = "okay";
};
```

Then run `make dtbs` to build the DTBs.

There is also the possibility to decompile/compile a DTB with [dtc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dtc.1.html).